# Include directory with subdirectories in SSH configuration: issue with autocomplete

Tags: bash, ssh

I am running OpenSSH 8.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to structure my .ssh/config file so that it includes directories with subdirectories:

```
Include config.d/*
Include config.d/dir1/*
Include config.d/dir2/*
Include config.d/dir3/*
```

If I have a host `remotevm` and I try the autocompletion when I type `ssh remotevm`, I get the following error:

```
$ ssh remosed: read error on /home/user/.ssh/config.d/dir1: Is a directory
sed: read error on /home/user/.ssh/config.d/dir2: Is a directory
sed: read error on /home/user/.ssh/config.d/dir3: Is a directory
awk: read error (Is a directory)
```

What can I do so that the autocompletion works again like before?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Specify in Include every single file without folders, like this:

```
Include config.d/myfile1.conf
Include config.d/dir1/myfile2.conf
Include config.d/dir1/myfile3.conf
```

To be more precise this has nothing to do with  the wildcard itself

It will work like this:

```
Include config.d/myfile1.conf
Include config.d/dir1/*
```

The first line of your example includes folders, that's not supported.